# Present perfect continuous for a short action?

Tags: meaning-in-context, present-perfect-progressive

This is from a novel:

The police is called because a man has urinated in a parking lot. When the police arrive 5 minutes later they ask the man: "Have you been urinating in the parking lot, sir?"

My question is: why is the continuous used? It only happened once and urinating is a short action. Is it used to express criticism?

Could the policeman have asked: "Have you urinated in the parking lot, sir?"

Comment: We often use Present Perfect Continuous when asking ***Have you been doing something you shouldn't**?* It's largely irrelevant whether the activity being queried was repeated and/or lasted long. What matters most is that Present Perfect Continuous implies ***strong relevance to time of speaking*** - which is obviously highly relevant if a representative of the authorities is asking you whether you've *[**very recently**] been **breaking the law***.

Comment: ...also note that although it doesn't always apply, the "non-continuous" verb forms tend to be ***Have you** [done something you **should** have]?*, and ***Did you** [do something you **shouldn't** have]?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica Would "have you urinated" be possible also in this situation? Because it is clear no one wants the man to urinate in the parking lot.

Comment: I'm not impressed with your example context, but I would point out that a nurse on her daily ward round is more likely to ask the patient ***Have** you been?* (euphemism for *Have you had a bowel movement today?*) because in that context, it's something they *want* you to have done. As opposed to ***Did** your child wet the bed last night?* (where ideally the answer wouldn't be in the affirmative! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica I have seen a British tv show where someone claims to have weed in the pool and they are asked: "have you urinated in the pool?" –

Comment: We're talking about a *very* fine aspect of English usage here, and there are always exceptions & sloppy scriptwriters anyway. But I'd say it's a racing certainty that most instances of [***Did you pee in***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Have+you+peed+in%2CDid+you+pee+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDid%20you%20pee%20in%3B%2Cc0) will be asking about whether you peed somewhere you *shouldn't*. Note that the alternative ***Have you peed in...*** is so uncommon as not to even figure on the chart with that one....

Comment: ...but note that with [***Did you give / Have you given...***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Did+you+give%2CHave+you+given&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDid%20you%20give%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHave%20you%20given%3B%2Cc0) (as likely to be positive as negative), both forms occur about equally often. I rest my case.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica "It's largely irrelevant whether the activity being queried was repeated and/or lasted long" So it may have happened only once?

Comment: Definitely. If someone is asked [***Have you been drinking**?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22have+you+been+drinking%22), that's often a somewhat rhetorical question (asked because the addressee is acting in ways that makes the speaker suspect he might be intoxicated). But there's absolutely no implication in such a question that the speaker thinks the other person *repeatedly* gets drunk (maybe they do, maybe they don't - it's irrelevant). And the activity needn't last *long* either - but the *Perfect* form implies *at least the **effects** continue until time of speaking.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers "been breaking the law." Can you explain why it is possible to say"been breaking the law" but not "been breaking my leg"? To break is a short action verb.

Comment: No, "to break" is ***not*** a "short action verb" in contexts like *breaking the law*.  You could ***break / be breaking** the law* continuously for many years in many contexts (being bigamously married, for example). Obviously it's a short duration action in the case of me *(literally)* breaking my leg, but that's not necessarily the case if someone is (more metaphorically) breaking my heart.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers: In my example the person is breaking the law by urinating in the parking lot once. In this context "to break the law" is not a short duration action either?

Comment: *In my example the person **breaks** the law by urinating in the parking lot*. It doesn't really make much difference whether you use a "continuous" verb form of not for something like that. But note that I think the PC probably wouldn't ask ***Have you urinated** in the parking lot, sir?* - I think he's be much more likely to phrase it as ***Did you urinate** in the parking lot, sir?*. On average, we tend to ask ***Have you** [done something you **should** have done]?* and ***Did you** [do something you **shouldn't** have done]?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers" Why can't I say: "is breaking the law"?

Comment: I never said you couldn't. In fact, I specifically said ***It doesn't really make much difference whether you use a "continuous" verb form or not*** (in your *exact* context here). You can't normally use a continuous form in something like ***He was breaking his leg***, because that really is an "instantaneous" action that doesn't actually span any significant period of time. But even if someone can [***piss like a horse***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22piss+like+a+horse%22) (stereotypically, ***rapidly and copiously***), the act of urinating takes time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is just that you wrote: "the person breaks (in bold) the law" instead of "breaking the law", like I wrote. I'm wondering why that is.

Comment: Sorry if that was confusing for you. My earlier comment could just as well have started with *In my example the person **is breaking** the law by urinating in the parking lot.* My point being It doesn't really make much difference *which* version you use. The only reason I chose to use the continuous in *my* version was because *you* had used Simple Past, and I meant to imply that both forms are valid, *and interchangeable*.